# Magento2: Connect to an external non Magento DB

Tags: magento2

Sometimes I need to connect to different databases, Mysql / Oracle etc. 
What is the best practice to do it in Magento2

Answer (score 4):

This is not officially supported. We are moving towards better modularization, with callers coming in via service contracts to restrict the API that would have to be reimplemented (default implementation can be replaced using di.xml file), but it will not be a simple job in Magento 2.0.0. We are moving that way, but no ETA when it will be "easy" to do.

For example, you could use plugins to intercept database calls or module calls; you could use di.xml to replace default implementations; etc. So there are ways to do it. (People do this in M1 sometimes.)

Answer (score 2):

It may not be "best practice" but in Magento 1 I once had to connect to a SQL Server to get some information. I just created the connection and put it in a Helper to be able to retrieve it from anywhere in the system.

I don't see why you couldn't do the same in Magento 2 (or at least try it)

Answer (score 2):

this is how I managed to do it. Don't know if it's the correct way but it works ( only mysql ):

app/etc/env.php

```
...
  'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'xxxx',
        'username' => 'yyyy',
        'password' => 'zzzz',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
      'myconnection' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'somedbname',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'yyyy',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'resource' => 
  array (
    'default_setup' => 
    array (
      'connection' => 'default',
    ),
      'myconnection' =>
    array (
      'connection' => 'myconnection',
    ),
  ),
...
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Test.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Page extends AbstractModel
{
    const UID = 'uid'; 

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'test'; // parent value is 'core_abstract'

    /**
     * Name of the event object
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'test'; // parent value is 'object'

    /**
     * Name of object id field
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = self::UID; // parent value is 'id'

    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Page');
    }

}
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Test.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Test extends AbstractDb
{

    protected $connectionName = 'myconnection';


    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        // Table Name and Primary Key column
        $this->_init('testtable', 'uid');
    }

}
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Test/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{

    protected $_idFieldName = \Vendor\Module\Model\Test::UID;

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Test', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test');
    }

}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Michele